# Unsatisfied link error for native library

Tags: android, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I developed applications which use native code. All of a sudden those are not working, giving error "Unsatisfied link error: Couldn't load native library from loader dalvik.System.pathClassLoader, findLibrary returned null. I restarted adt twice. Still getting the same error. Applications which are not using native code, are working fine.

Comment: Have you loaded that compiled or newly generated library using `System.loadLibrary("library_name");` ??????

Comment: Yes I loaded the library.

Comment: You almost give no information about what's going on inside. Without giving out the implementation details, it's really hard to find out what's going on without playing the guessing game. Please do give out the details.

Answer (score 0):

The error implies that the program is not able to find the shared libraries that you would have created.
Which devices did you try it on ?
You can check once if they are available in libs directory of your app . [/data/data/app_id/lib ]. Also check if armv7 support is required and if the directory is there in the libs , is .so present there.

Comment: I tried on virtual device. Not on a real one. .so file is present. "/data/data/app_id/lib" there is no data folder in my application. there never was.

Comment: /data/data/app_id/lib , here app_id has to be replaced with your app directory. Me wanted you to check in /data/data/your_app_id/libs for the .so .
[[ adb root --> adb remount --> adb shell --> cd /data/data/Your_app_directory/lib ]] . Post the result of ls -l there.
Please share the Android.mk and Application.mk files snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working. I deleted all my virtual devices and then created a new one. However it's showing "skipped 264 frames. application may be doing too much work on main thread" many times and whenever we press a button, displaying this message in log "error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg"
thanks.